# How do I study linguistic features of NLP libraries like spacy/NLTK in-depth?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, linguistics, nlu

## My Objective

I am trying to do Natural Language Processing(NLU to be precise) with spaCy. But the more I dive into this wonderful library, the more I realize that I need to understand some linguistics first.

## The Problem

The problem is, spacy explains NLP with terminologies that just don't seem to follow a single branch of linguistics. I am new to NLP and if anyone can give me some pointers on how to study linguistics for Natural Language Understanding, I think I would have an easier time getting a grasp of this library.

I have tried understanding Morphology but stuff like Part of Speech tagging, syntactic dependencies, etc. all seem to relate to different concepts that are implemented together. How much theory and in which subfields of linguistics do I need to study to have a strong grasp of all the concepts used?

I want to learn the theory so I know what to do even if spacy is missing something that I might wanna use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read an overview like this one [Introduction to Linguistics for Natural Language Processing](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1314/L100/introling.pdf) and then would dive deeper into the topics that interest you.